# Is there a React hooks feature that has the same functionality as passing a callback as the second argument to setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Using hooks, I would like to execute a function only after a particular call to update state. For instance, I would like to achieve the same functionality that this does (assuming I already have already instantiated this piece of state.)

```
setState({name: Joe}, () => console.log('hi'));
```

I do *not* want this to log 'hi' every time that name changes, I only want to log 'hi' after this particular setState call has been executed.

This

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('hi');
}, [name]);
setName('Joe');
setName('Bob'); // only log 'hi' after this one!
setName('Joe');
setName('Bob');
```

will not work for my purposes because I don't want to log 'hi' every time name changes. The value in the setName call does not matter. The console.log must be executed only after this particular setName call has been executed.

Update: I was overthinking this. I was asking this question because I had a piece of state called "mode" that determined some conditional rendering through a switch statement:

```
switch(mode) {
    case foo: return <Foo />
    case bar: return <Bar />
}
```

I was only wanting to fire some logic when mode was a certain value (aka a certain component would be rendered). I simply moved this logic down a level into the lower-level component and used

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    someLogic();
}, []);
```

in order to only fire this logic on component render.

Answer (score 0):

State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing here

```
const useStateWithCallback = val => {
   const callback = useRef();
   const [state,setState] = useState(val);

   useEffect(() => {
      callback.current && callback.current(state);
      callback.current = null;
   },[callback,state]);

   return [
      state,
      useCallback((arg,cb) => {
        callback.current = cb;
        return setState(arg);
      },[callback,setState])) // these are safe to omit, right?
   ]

}
```

EDIT: not to be too verbose, but usage:

```
import { useStateWithCallback } from './useStateWithCallback';

const MyCmp = () => {
    const [name,setName] = useStateWithCallback('');

    ...
    setName('joe',state => console.log(`Hi ${state}`));
    ...

}
```